# How to read the contents of a single file in SharePoint Online using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have the following url which displays the metadata of the file when put in the browser but I want the actual file content.

```
https://mySite/_api/web/folders/getbyurl('Shared%20Documents')/folders/getbyurl('09.%20SharePoint%20Tutorials')/files/GetByUrl('SharePoint%20365%20Co-authoring%20excel%20files.docx')
```

I have tried doing the following but I just get a 400 error when trying to execute the query on line 4:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("mySite");

File f = clientContext.Web.Folders.GetByUrl("Shared Documents").Folders.GetByUrl("09. SharePoint Tutorials").Files.GetByUrl("SharePoint 365 Co-authoring excel files.docx");
clientContext.Load(f);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

FileInformation fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)f.ServerRelativeUrl);
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInformation.Stream))
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below for your reference:

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";

var login = "lz@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "xxx";

var securePassword = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
var web = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(web);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var filePath = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/09.%20SharePoint%20Tutorials/SharePoint%20365%20Co-authoring%20excel%20files.docx";
FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, filePath);

using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInformation.Stream))
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Swapping in my information I got: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.' on the  ctx.ExecuteQuery();line

Comment: It seems my problem was I made a .net core console program instead of .net framework console program. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To obtain the full path you could clic on "details" and then "path access".